# Converting PHP to JavaScript. Store keys/values into an array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to convert the following PHP code to JavaScript, This is an array of key/value pairs in PHP:

**PHP code:**

```
$countries = array("AF"=>"AFGHANISTAN","AX"=>"ALAND ISLANDS");
```

What's the best way to do this in jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: Note also that jQuery IS JavaScript, so there is no such thing as a jQuery array, only a JS array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var countries = {
  "AF": "AFGHANISTAN",
  "AX": "ALAND ISLANDS"
}
```

Then, to get the value for a given key, use one of the following:

```
var af = countries["AF"];
var ax = countries.AF;
```

Answer (score 4):

javascript doesn't have an associative array (like in PHP, your example above), instead, we call it javascript object:

```
var countries = {
    'AF': 'AFGHANISTAN', 
    'AX': 'ALAND ISLANDS'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
<script>
    var countries = <?php echo json_encode($countries); ?>;
</script>
```

That's what will be stored in `countries`:

```
{
    AF : "AFGHANISTAN",
    AX : "ALAND ISLANDS"
}
```

If you just want to reproduce such a data structure in JS, use [objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) as stated in the other posts.

Comment: Sorry but the edit changes the meaning of my original answer, and makes not much sense at all - no strings are involved at all, I just go from PHP array to JS object.